# What database engine uses FILE001.DAT, FILE003.DAT, SYMBOLS.IDX?

Tags: database, export

I am trying to migrate a database, but I cannot find which database it is.

The database files are like the following:

```
FILE001.DAT
FILE003.DAT
FILE004.DAT
.
.
FILE093.DAT
FILEM02.DBT
FILEM05.DBT
.
.
.
FILEM21.DBT
SYMBOLS.IDX
SYMBOLS.DAT
```

There are .DAT, .IDX and DBT files.
How can I read the data and database schema from these files;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [fileinfo.com entry](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/dbt), this is [dBASE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase).

As for migrating the database, you can try downloading the [drivers](http://www.dbase.com/ODBCSummary.asp) and connecting via ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

Should be dBase, if you have FoxPro laying around then try opening it with that

Answer (score 1):

You can find a dBase tool on [this link](http://www.jansfreeware.com/), on the left menu option "database", right menu "MyDBF_3"